# Как убрать замену \ на / в ответе Json Php

Tags: php, json

Ребят, есть вот такой код

```
<?php
include '../mysql.php';
if (isset($_GET['newsid'])) {
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `newsid` = '{$_GET['newsid']}'") as $row)
    {
        $array = array(
            "ownerid" => "{$row['ownerid']}",
            "newsid" => "{$row['newsid']}",
            "Description" => $row['Description'],
            "url" => $row['url'],
            "imageUrl" => $row['imageUrl'],
            "pictureid" => $row['pictureid'],
        );
    }
    if ($_GET['newsid'] != $row['newsid']) {
        echo "Нет новостей!";
    } elseif ($_GET['newsid'] == "") {
        echo "Пустое значение!";
    } else {
        $json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $json;
    }
}
```

И есть проблема с выводом ссылок, ведь ответ получается вот таким:

```
{"ownerid":"1","newsid":"1","Описание":"test","url":"https:\/\/static.mk.ru\/upload\/entities\/2021 \/03\/20\/07\/статьи\/detailPicture\/00\/c0\/a4\/82\/86c7ad95c204c4ce048acb6252a23671.jpg","imageUrl":"https:\/\/static.mk.ru \/upload\/entities\/2021\/03\/20\/07\/articles\/detailPicture\/00\/c0\/a4\/82\/86c7ad95c204c4ce048acb6252a23671.jpg","pictureid":"1" }
```

Как вы можете увидеть, в ссылках к \ добавился /, как убрать это? Чтобы ссылки выводились так-же как они записаны в базеданных.

Comment: А зачем? На содержимое это никак не влияет, зато защищает от возможных уязвимостей

Comment: @andreymal На содержимое не влияет?? Серьезно?? Перейди по ссылке из ответа, проверь как оно не влияет...

Comment: Так не надо напрямую из json-текста копировать, надо сперва распарсить и json-парсер автоматически уберёт всё экранирование

Comment: @andreymal У меня есть еще C# код который обрабатывает этот ответ, и он не может почему-то убрать это...

Comment: Значит C# код написан неправильно. С точки зрения json-синтаксиса `"/"` и `"\/"` это одинаковые строки и любой нормальный json-парсер должен уметь такое обрабатывать

Comment: @andreymal это экранирование можно убрать или нет?

Comment: Но вообще по сути вопроса в документации описаны все флаги, среди которых есть JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES https://www.php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php

Comment: Как и писал Андрей, php работает корректно. править нужно C#. Поэтому код приёмника в студию

Comment: И тем не менее, есть вещи (например `\n` или `\"`), экранирование которых отключить нельзя, потому что это сломало бы синтаксис json. Поэтому исправлять кривой C# код обязательно нужно в любом случае